# synchronization of ingested live streams on media server & playback device (obs)

Tags: streaming, broadcasting

I have multiple input sources for A/V streams I want to publish to a media server, and then have those stream broadcasts to be able to be sychronized for playback, for instance, as two separate media sources in OBS.

I have been investigating different technologies, stream protocols, media servers, etc to achieve the result im seeking.  So far, I have read up on RTSP (RTP/RTCP) protocol and having the the senders use features of RTP to sync to a common NTP clock that the receivers (rtpendpoints) would sync to as well.  the playback device, i would assume have to have its system time synced to the same NTP server too.

My question is what are some of the simplest ways to deploy such a setup?  Can I use WebRTC to stream to a media server (Ant Media Server or Kurento?)  If I want the streams not only in synch at re-broadcast,  would I want to broadcast the ingested streams via RTSP protocol that would then be used as media sources in OBS?  What else would I need to do to ensure synchronization (i.e,  NTP synching,  encoding via Gstreamer, rtpbin, etc?)